# Wikiplex - What does it do exactly?

Tags: .net, wiki

I was looking for a .net MVC wiki and stumbled across Wikiplex.

I don't understand what it does. Maybe I just don't understand how wiki engines work.

It says on [here](http://wikiplex.codeplex.com/documentation) that you just need to add a reference to the wikiplex .dll and then add these lines:

```
var engine = new WikiPlex.WikiEngine();
string output = engine.Render("This is my wiki source!");
```

But I don't understand how this works, what it does for me. What does it mean. Can someone explain what it is exactly, how it works, and how I would use it to add a wiki to my site?

Thanks,

Richard